# Sum a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I currently am running this select query (shorter than the original):

```
SELECT 'website' service, COUNT(*) 
FROM website 
UNION 
SELECT 'vps' service, COUNT(*) 
FROM vps 
UNION 
SELECT 'other' service, 
COUNT(*) 
FROM other;
```

I get this result:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgFGr.png)

```
+---------+----------+
| service | COUNT(*) |
+---------+----------+
| website |        2 |
| vps     |        1 |
| other   |        2 |
+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I'd like to add up all the results which are listed in the `COUNT(*)` column.

Expected result:

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|        5 |
+----------+
1 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: `I'd like to add up all these results in the "COUNT(*)" collum.` how? Can you post the expected result ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha I've updated the post to contain this information.

Comment: There are a few possible ways to skin this cat.  The first question you're really going to have to answer is do you need the results of the first query?  You could return the initial result set, then use a Compute function on the resulting DT or Linq query to sum it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment you should add `SUM` in an outer query.

Try:

```
SELECT sum(t1.nr_count)
FROM (
      SELECT 'website' service, COUNT(*) as nr_count  FROM website 
      UNION 
      SELECT 'vps' service, COUNT(*)  as nr_count FROM vps 
      UNION 
      SELECT 'other' service, COUNT(*) as nr_count FROM other       
    ) as t1;
```

Comment: Looks like that worked! Thank you very much.
I was unaware of how to sum a select query so that really helps me with my further projects.